# python argparse: unrecognized arguments

Tags: python, argparse

When I run `parsePlotSens.py -s bw hehe`, it says that `hehe` is an unrecognized argument. However, if I run `parsePlotSens.py hehe -s bw`, it's OK. Ideally, I would like it work for both cases.

Any tips? The following is my code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__' :

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='parsePlotSens');
    parser.add_argument('-s', '--sort', nargs =1, action = 'store', choices = ['mcs', 'bw'], default='mcs', help=sorthelp)
    parser.add_argument('filename', nargs ='+', action = 'store')
    option = parser.parse_args(sys.argv)
```

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Do not pass `sys.argv` as an argument to `parse_args`. Just use

```
option = parser.parse_args()
```

If you do pass `sys.argv` to `parse_args`, then the path or name of the script itself is the first item in `sys.argv` and thus becomes the value of `option.filename`. The `hehe` then becomes an unknown argument.

If you omit `sys.argv` then `parse_args` parses `sys.argv` as expected.

Comment: Alternatively you can call parser.parse_args(sys.argv[1:]). Internally argparse does just that.

Comment: @MarioVilas now why in the world would you want to reimplement something that is handled by the library you're using? There is no reason to pick this option over omitting `sys.argv` altogether

Comment: @aidandeno MarioVilas comment could be useful for someone who wants to call a function they've written that calls `argparse.ArgumentParser` and gets the arguments for `argparse.ArgumentParser` from its parameters. For example, maybe someone wants to know how to call `theirArgumentHandlerFunction` without getting "unrecognized arguments" - by calling it like MarioVilas comment suggests, as `theirArgumentHandlerFunction(sys.argv[1:])`.

Comment: @MarioVilas When writing unit tests, it's better to pass the `argv` into the function instead of overriding the value of `sys.argv`.

Answer (score 88):

You can get around this by allowing unknown arguments

Replace

```
args = parser.parse_args()
```

with

```
args, unknown = parser.parse_known_args()
```

Comment: This is easiest and convenient solution.

Answer (score 5):

Also, as a complement to unutbu's answer, storing the arguments in a dictionary this way makes the tests easy:

```
args = vars(parser.parse_args())
print args
```

Prints the dictionary:

```
{'sort': ['bw'], 'filename': ['hehe']}
```

Like :

```
if args['sort'] == 'bw':
    # code here

...
```

Comment: That's _always_ `False` because the string `'bw'` will _never_ be equal to a list with that string in it. I fail to see the reason to use `vars()` here.  If you omit that pointless conversion the test becomes `if args.sort == 'bw':`. That's how it is supposed to be used.

Answer (score 3):

To complete this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48057478/3751268) here I provide an example to get and parse the unknown arguments:

```py
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
# we only have a know argument  as key-pair --known KNOWN
parser.add_argument('--known')

# test with known un unknown variables
args, unknown = parser.parse_known_args(["--known", "var", "--unknown", "bar", "--flag"])
```

`unknown` return a list like `["--unknown", "bar", "--flag"]`. We just need to parse it:

```
keypairs = dict([unknown[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(unknown), 1) if unknown[i].startswith("--") and not (unknown[i+1:i+2]+["--"])[0].startswith("--")])

flags = [unknown[i] for i in range(0, len(unknown), 2) if (unknown[i+1:i+2]+["--"])[0].startswith("--")]
```

Answer (score 2):

My situation not same with the question, but the error is same.

My situation:

1. I have a remote dev(SFTP) with windows pycharm, and upload to run with linux.
2. the python command have some line break with `\` in my bash file, like

   ```
   python args_config.py \
       --arg1="hello" \
       --arg2="world"
   ```

and raise a `python argparse: unrecognized arguments` args not found error.

the problem is the bash file line breaking is different in windows and linux,

just setting with pycharm `File -> Line Separators -> LF - Unix and OS X (\n)`

upload to linux and run bash file, it works!

Answer (score 1):

Very useful thread. I had pretty much the same question as @Yan Zhu, @unutbu and @FacePalm's answeres were good, but I need to take in argv also. I came up with this, figured good because it allows me to write unit tests that don't require sys.argv arguments.

```
import argparse, sys


def parse(arg_list):
     p = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="my simple app")
     p.add_argument('-z', '--zeta', type=str, default='[zeta from default]')
     p.add_argument('-a', '--application', type=str, default='[application from default]')
     return p.parse_known_args(arg_list)


code_args = [ '-a', 'a from code', '-q', 'q from code', '-o', 'o from code']

print(parse(code_args + sys.argv[1:]))
```

When you add a runtime param from intellij like this `-a 'a from intellij'` the results look like so.

```
/usr/local/bin/python3.7 /Users/me/IdeaProjects/co-util-py/test/varargstest.py -a "a from intellij"

(Namespace(application='a from intellij', other='o from code'), ['-q', 'q from code'])
```

You can see that argparse doesn't drop the q, but it also doesn't parse it.

Also, after lots of brain strain and testing, the only real difference between sys.argv and a list created is that `sys.argv[0]` is the name of the program that is being called. Drop that from the list and it doesn't matter.