# Why did Python `argparse` stop documenting nargs=REMAINDER?

Tags: python, argparse

In the documentation for Python's `argparse` module, the [3.8 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/argparse.html#nargs) states that `nargs` may be set to:

> `argparse.REMAINDER`. All the remaining command-line arguments are gathered into a list. This is commonly useful for command line utilities that dispatch to other command line utilities.

This has been removed from the [3.9 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/argparse.html#nargs), though there is no mention of it being deprecated, nor any good reason to do so that I can see given given that it provides useful functionality not apparently provided by other means.¹ Its existence is still mentioned in passing [elsewhere in the page](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/argparse.html#intermixed-parsing):

> These [intermixed] parsers do not support all the argparse features, and will raise exceptions if unsupported features are used. In particular, subparsers, argparse.REMAINDER, and mutually exclusive groups that include both optionals and positionals are not supported.

But even this is removed in the [3.10 documentation]. Yet the feature persists even in Python 3.11.4, the latest released version.

So why has it been removed from the documentation?

---

I ask this because the answer seems likely to bear directly on several other related questions I have about programming argument parsers in Python. (The particular situations where I was, am, and may continue to use `nargs=REMAINDER` are large enough that I believe that they should be posted as separate questions, if necessary.) The considerations include:

- Is the API broken in some way for my purposes, and does this imply that my code that uses it also broken?
- Should I look for a replacement for this API?
- Should I continue to use this API in new code? After all, it hasn't been deprecated.
- Should I be converting existing code that uses this API to use something else?

(Note too that the answers to questions like this will not only depend on the particular context in which `nargs=REMAINDER` is used, but may also be considered matters of opinion, which is another reason to leave them beyond the scope of this question.)

---

¹ `nargs=REMAINDER` is different from `nargs='*'`: using `REMAINDER` means that argparse will not attempt to parse options (starting with `-`) from that point on. Thus, with `REMAINDER`, `mycmd -q run bash -c exit` will not attempt to parse the `-c` as an option to `mycmd`, but instead the line will be treated as `mycmd -q run -- bash -c exit` is with `'*'`.

[3.10 documentation]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a question about a decision, which can only properly be answered by the person or people who made that decision. Any reasoning anyone else could offer would be purely speculative. The most appropriate place to ask about the Python documentation - to question a decision or suggest an improvement - is https://discuss.python.org/c/documentation/26.

Comment: Removing it from the documentation has been discussed in the GITHUB issues (open or closed).  I don't remember commenting on it, but my memory is that its implementation was buggy enough that the devs though it simplest to just un-document it, while still leaving it in the code.  Therefor, use it at your own risk, and don't come complaining if it does not work as you want.

Comment: I wrote that `intermixed` parser and comment - quite some time ago  As noted I made no effort to test this combination of features.  Also you have found the (rough) double dash equivalent.

Comment: As a matter of curiosity, there's another undocumented `nargs`, `'A...'`, which expects at least one (non-dash) string.  That's used by the `subparsers`, `argparse.PARSER`.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/trhpow/undocumented_features_eg_argparseremainder/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feel free to skip the "Summary" section at the bottom if you don't want
to read all the details.

This is based on the mostly excellent links provided in [Nick ODell's
answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76956236/107294), particular comments in those links, and other comments provided
here (particuarly by hpaulj; hat tip to him).

##### The Problem

A key design decision in [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) is that it parses options *anywhere*
in the command line, i.e., `ls somedir/ -l` is just as valid as `ls -l somedir/`. (Note that this differs from [`getopt`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/getopt.html), where the non-option
arguments would be `['somedir/', '-l']` in the first example above.)

The end user can apply parsing to only a prefix of a command line by using
the special `--` "option," which changes the part of the command line
that's passed to the parser *before* the parser runs, but clearly
developers wanting to use `argparse.REMAINDER` are wanting to avoid making
the user do this.

Unfortunately, it seems that `nargs=REMAINDER` doesn't fit well into this
"parse options anywhere in the command line" system. I am not aware of the
exact reasons for this (some of which may be inherent in the logic of what
argparse is trying to do, as opposed to just a matter of doing the
programming); I think that would be a suitable topic for another question.

This started with a bug report ["argparse.REMAINDER doesn't work as first
argument"](https://bugs.python.org/issue17050) (since [moved to GitHub](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/61252)), which could also be
described as a situation where the *only* argument uses `nargs=REMAINDER`.
This brings up a relatively subtle problem for which there's much
discussion, including how `nargs=REMAINDER` should work in sub-parsers,
which itself opens up a whole new can of worms.

[paulj3's comment](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/61252#issuecomment-1093606580) goes into much of the detail about the difficulties of
determining `REMAINDER` behaviour, determining what its behaviour *should*
be, and documenting all of this; responses point out that he may not be
correct about certain details. It also points out that the original case
doesn't appear to need or want `argparse`:

> If you don't want such a gatekeeper [by which he means functionality like
> `--` —cjs], why [use] argparse at all? Why not use sys.argv[1:] directly?"

##### The Removal

In the comment above, paulj3 makes a key point:

> So some sort of warning about the limitations of REMAINDER would be good.
> But the trick is to come up with something that is clear but succinct.
> The argparse documentation is already daunting to beginners.

This is generally agreed to be difficult, and nobody seems actually to have
proposed specific changes to the documentation, so paulj3 says in a later
comment:

> Since this feature is buggy, and there isn't an easy fix, we should
> probably remove any mention of it from the docs. We can still leave it as
> an undocumented legacy feature.
>
> There is precedent for leaving nargs constants undocumented.
> argparse.PARSER ('+...') is used by the subparser mechanism, but is not
> documented. https://bugs.python.org/issue16988

This seemed to attract enough agreement that PRs were submitted and all
mention of `REMAINDER` was removed.

##### The Alternatives

(Note: this is not technically related to the original question here, but I
bring this up mainly because of the common `parse_known_args()` confusion
that arises in discussions of `nargs=REMAINDER`.)

[Nick ODell's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76956236/107294) suggests, based on answers to ["python argparse:
unrecognized arguments"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17118999/107294), that using `Parser.parse_known_args()`
instead of `Parser.parse_args()` is a replacement for `nargs=REMAINDER`.
Some answers to the question ["Getting the remaining arguments in
argparse"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22850332/107294) do the same.

These are *not* correct. The "unrecognised arguments" question is even
dealing with an entirely different problem that `nargs=REMAINDER` will not
solve. (The actual solution was not to pass `sys.argv` to `parse_args()`.)
And though there are two mentions of `parse_known_args()` in the original
bug report discussion, those are is simply related to demonstrating
`argparse` behaviour, and it is never suggested as an alternative.

As for what to do in *your* particular program, that's heavily dependent on
the program itself and your aims, and would require a separate question
giving a lot more detail about the particular situation. As far as I can
tell, this is *just* a documentation change, and  `nargs=REMAINDER` appears
not to be going away, so you could continue to use that. This is discussed
in more detail in several answers to ["Getting the remaining arguments in
argparse"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22850332/107294) (note again that some of those answers incorrectly
suggest `parse_known_args()`). [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49351471/107294) gives code for
several solutions to that particular question, and a good warning:

> The best all-around answer so far is `nargs=REMAINDER`, but it might
> really depend on your use case.

Other alternatives include [`getopt`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/getopt.html) (which always stops at the first
non-option, avoiding the problem via different and less featureful parsing
logic) and, as suggested above, simply using `sys.argv[1:]` if that fits
your situation.

##### Summary

`nargs=REMAINDER` is *very* hard to document, and may not even fit well
into the design of `argparse`, causing complex edge cases. So it appears
that to avoid further complexity in already complex documentation, for an
awkward feature that doesn't fit well with the overall philosophy of how
`argparse` parses arguments, it was felt best simply to remove it from the
documentation.

(Whether this was the best way to go is of course a matter of opinion, but
to me, "don't make the documentation more complex" seems a valid argument
to make.)

Answer (score 5):

You can see the discussion about why this was removed [here](https://bugs.python.org/issue17050).

Essentially, it was removed from the documentation because it was very fragile. The original author of the feature wrote a documentation example, but very small changes to that example (like putting the `REMAINDER` argument first) break it. Removing it from documentation steers new users away from it, without the backward compatibility problems of fully removing it. (Note: this characterization is disputed; see comments for why.)

Instead of getting the remaining arguments, an alternative approach is to get unrecognized arguments using `parser.parse_known_args()`. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17118999/python-argparse-unrecognized-arguments). This approach is still documented.

See [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/18661) and [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/103586) for the PRs which removed the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the references; those are good. However, there are two issues with this answer that keep me from upvoting it. 
1. I don't accept your conclusion that you can't put a `REMAINDER` argument first makes it "very fragile." (Nor is this the consensus of the thread you linked.) This is probably not the place for further discussion of your and my opinions on this, however.

Comment: 2. You can _not_ replace `REMAINDER` with `parse_known_args()` since only `REMAINDER` can be used to specify a position at which to stop consuming options. `parse_known_args()` will consume options even if they were clearly intended for the other command, if it has an option with the same name. (Or even a similar name, if you didn't explicitly disallow abbreviations.) I've [demonstrated this here](https://github.com/0cjs/example-code/tree/main/py-argparse-remainder).

Comment: @cjs I don't necessarily disagree; I'm just trying to summarize 13 pages of discussion, while providing alternatives that *are* documented. If you don't agree with the discussion, then you can continue to use the feature. If you don't agree with the decision to remove the docs, you can ask on the python bug tracker to have it reinstated. But I'm not a Python dev, and I have no power to help you.

Comment: I'm an argparse dev, though not nearly as active now as I once was.  The module is old enough that development is slow, and favors maintaining backward compatibility, rather than adding new features.  It is easier to tweak the documenation to match the code than the other way around.  While it is the 'official' parser, there are good third party alternatives.  Also users are welcome to implement their own changes; the code is good OOP, so changes and enhancements are easily added with subclassing.

Comment: @NickODell To be clear, the issues are: 1. I don't think your summary is a fair one; I think it would be more accurate to say something like "whether it works 'properly' and is useful is disputed." 2. What you provided is an alternative that works differently, and is a substitute in some cases but not others, but your text pretty clearly claims that `REMAINDER` duplicates `parse_known_args()`, which it doesn't. These are the things that are keeping me from upvoting and accepting your answer; the links (including the `parse_known_args()` suggestion itself, are exactly what I was looking for.